# Sqlite update query error

Tags: sqlite

I want to add something into every row in a column, however I have some difficulties with it. There are already some data in the rows, and I don't want to lose those, just add this new one.

```
Table name is GroupList
Column name is Commands
```

In the rows of commands data is seperated by a comma.

Here is my mess:

```
UPDATE GroupList SET Commands = ',stats.highscores', WHERE Commands != ',stats.highscores'
```

The , before the stats.highscores is a must. I have no idea why it won't work.
I tried looking up the error code in google, but I still get the same error.

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
[mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

I would really appriciate some help with this. Sorry if I wrote something stupid, I'm new with sqlite.

edit: I'm using sqlite manager firefox addon

Comment: What are you using to execute the SQLite? You should get a better error message. The SQL you have posted isn't valid.

Comment: Have a look at www.sqliteexpert.com for an alternative tool to help with your SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comma after the `SET` statement which makes the SQL you have invalid.

The statement you have will update the `Commands` column for all existing rows where the `Commands` column does not have the value `,stats.highscores`.

To create a new row you need to use `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO GroupList (Commands) VALUES (',stats.highscores');
```

**EDIT**

To update this value when there is no current value use

```
UPDATE GroupList 
  SET Commands = ',stats.highscores' 
WHERE 
  Commands IS NULL 
  OR Commands = '';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Works but erases the existing data in the Commands columns, and I need to keep that.

Comment: Your where clause needs to exclude any existing values but your checking for the value you want to insert. Is the column NULL or an empty string?

Comment: The default value is null

Comment: Added existing values, it still erases everything. I will try out the tool you recommended and report back.:)

Comment: Ah that is such an awesome tool. Much more user friendly than what I was using. Also finally success.After I get my 15 repu i will come back and upvote your answer. Many thanks for your time and help.:)

Answer (score 1):

The Comma before WHERE does not belong.

```
SET Commands = ',stats.highscores', WHERE
```

Maybe use NOT LIKE rather than !=

UPDATE GroupList SET Commands = ',stats.highscores', WHERE Commands NOT LIKE ',stats.highscores'

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however i get the same error.:\

Comment: Have removed the comma yet?

Comment: Yes, tried. It seems the tool i was using is a mess. With SQlite expert personal I was able to solve the problem and run the query successfully. After I get my 15 repu i will come back and upvote your answer. Thank you:)

Comment: You should have it now.